# こういうとき need help figuring out this word

Tags: grammar

Im seeing this word quite a lot through the video, but I cant figure out its meaning.

[image]

Comment: Try looking up こういう and とき separately in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably translate the phrase こういうとき (*kou iu toki*) into something like "in this kind of situation" or "in this kind of a time". For example, the sentence at the bottom of your picture (こういうときは何と言いますか？ or *ko iu toki wa, nan to iimasu ka?* in Roomaji) literally means "What do you say in this kind of a time?" or even more literally, "As for this kind of time, what to say?". I'm not quite sure if that's what you wanted to know, but from what I took your question to mean I hope it somewhat answers your question. :)